# From Date will not be accept earlier than 13 months in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here i have "From Date" and "To Date" with submit button. And i'm using telerik radate control for this project. So, I couldn't add that telerik control.

Here Everything is fine for my requirement and one enhancement is there.

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/4tyJ4/

**Additional Info :**
The “From Date” will not be earlier than 13 months back compare with "To Date".

How to add the validation for this? looking for your help.

Comment: I suppose the best way would be to take the current date and find our what the date was 13 months ago and compare with the date they entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set the month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) to a date in the past and compare with that:

```
var today = new Date(), // you can use only one Date, this is only for clarity
    back = new Date();
back.setMonth( today.getMonth() - 13);
return fromDate > back;
```

---

Fixing the day as suggested by @mplungjan:

```
var months = 13;
if (back.getMonth() == (today.getMonth() - months % 12 + 12 + 1) % 12)
   back.setDate(-1);
```

---

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUJGz/7/): Use a clone of `endDate` instead of `today` to init `back`, then compare with `startDate`:

```
var back = new Date(endDate);
…
return startDate > back;
```

Comment: can you fork my fiddle for this solution?Thanks

Comment: Umm, your fiddle does not contain any validation code. Please add some basis code where I can integrate my solution

Comment: Watch it when you go from the 31st back to a month with less days

Comment: I suggest normalizing the date to be ealier than the 29th, go back and add days back to as close to the actual date as possible

Comment: Yes, going back 1 month from the March 31st lands on March 2nd. But would you have expected Feb 28th? It is a valid solution for that undetermined state, and it depends on the OP's needs whether it is OK or not.

Comment: As per the Bergi code, I'm getting one error when i implemented. error is [Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'months' is undefined].Anyone can help on this?

Comment: The current fiddle should not throw errors. If so, please post their error messages.

Answer (score 3):

```
var toDate= urToDate;
var fromDate= urFromDate;
fromDate.setMonth(toDate.getMonth()+13);

if(fromDate>toDate)
{
//Do your work
}
else
{
//from date is older
}
```

Comment: I will try and let you know.Thanks

Comment: Yes its not working. I got answer from someone anyway thanks for your help.