# Javascript Validation for- "From Date" should not be prior 13 months from "To Date"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [From Date will not be accept earlier than 13 months in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054405/from-date-will-not-be-accept-earlier-than-13-months-in-javascript)

I Am trying to form a “From Date” will not be earlier than 13 months back compare with "To Date". So this is my requirement. I did one poc for this.

I have two more validation like "To Date must be greater than From Date" its fine for me.
I need a help for 13 months back validation. If you have nay clarification please raise..

http://jsfiddle.net/ssthil/DUJGz/3/

Comment: Dude, are you kidding? You already got two answers for that! If you need further explanations, just add some comments there.

Comment: @MaxArt No, I'm not kidding. I need your help for this, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just like I said [at the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12054561/1048572). Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DUJGz/7/

Comment: I'm getting error when I implement. Like[Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'months' is undefined]

Comment: You're right, updated. Did not test it.

Comment: Alright, some other bugs fixed (e.g. you had used < instead of >)

Comment: where i missed when i implemented?

Comment: when comparing `endDate` with `today`

Comment: If is this from my end please guide me how can i solve this issue

Comment: I already did, just compare your code with mine latest.

Comment: can i have your latest code please?

Comment: Its very great.. Thank you so much...I got the solution from your help...thanks again..